# justify-content-end bootstrap no me esta funcionanco

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando justificar el contenido de un `<div>` a la derecha con *Bootstrap*, pero no se por qué no funciona.

El código es una simplificación de lo que yo estoy haciendo:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssBootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="jsBootstrap/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jsBootstrap/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>            
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container my-1">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 bg-danger justify-content-start">             
               <input type="checkbox" id="terminos" name="terminos"><label for="terminos">He leido los terminos</label>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 bg-warning justify-content-end">
               <input type="submit" id="pagar" name="pagar" value="Confirmar pedido">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo añade la clase [`d-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors) al elemento `div` de la columna: `<div class="col-6 bg-warning d-flex justify-content-end">`. De hecho la primera columna también deberías añadirle esa clase. Saludos

Comment: Esas utilidades deben ir en contenedores con el módulo flexbox, Bootstrap tiene la clase `.d-flex`. Puedes ver más info acá: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: genial, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que modificar el justify del div y el equivalente del item.
Te paso un fiddle para con el ejemplo

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>            
   </head>
   <body>
      
      <div class=" my-1">
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <div class="bg-danger align-content-end">             
               <input type="checkbox" id="terminos" name="terminos"><label for="terminos">He leido los terminos</label>                
            </div>
            <div class="bg-warning  align-content-end">
               <input type="submit" id="pagar" name="pagar" value="Confirmar pedido">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```